# Anime about a kid and ghost mother in a shrine or cemetery

Tags: story-identification, anime, horror

I must have watched this somewhere around 2004-2007, at most 2010 but I doubt it. I don’t know if this is a short movie or an episode.

Its about a kid that gets to hang around in a forest-like place close to his house (probably his patio or something).  Something keeps calling him to some sort of shrine in a cemetery in the forest, probably his mother’s tomb. He keeps getting scared but feels a lot of curiosity and anxiety to go there. Finally, at some point he decides to enter that place. Its like a tomb, he has to descend using some stairs to get in. Opens the door. Inside the shrine there’s a small room with concrete walls I believe, and a square in the floor with running water. Then a jump scare happens and some spirit shows up, angry and attacks the kid. It was some ugly ghost, female-ish, probably his mother.

Turned off the tv from the jump scare, never saw what that even was (it was on cable tv). The show had a serious tone, sort of like horror, with no comic relief parts or super powers, regular looking people, probably not bleach. The kid goes to school at some point I believe.